# Why do I are my quads outlined when rendered?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I have a 3x3 quad wall I am rendering to. I render to a 3x3 because the complete image exceeds the maximum single texture limit. So I've cut the image into a 3x3.

The issue I'm having is that when rendered to screen as I move the camera along the Z axis I am seeing the quads outlined most of the time. The image is cut exactly at he correct height and with to allow perfect 8532 x 5832 squares.

Does anyone have any ideas how to prevent the outlines from showing up?

This is an example of expected image:
[image]

This is an example of the same area at different Z and the quad out lines are visible.
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show what you mean.